# How to run custom scheme written in node.js using readline in emacs?

Tags: scheme, inferior-lisp

I have Scheme interpreter written in JavaScript that run on top of Node.js the problem is that when I run run-scheme and I enter something it give double echo:

```
lips> 10
10
10
lips>
```

if I run ansi-term it works normally. I have the same issue if I run from `emacs -q`. What may be the problem? My scheme use readline in Node.js, it works fine from real terminal emulator, outside of Emacs. It also works with other scheme interpreter like guile.

Anybody have idea what may went wrong, and why I have double echo?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use:

```
(setq comint-process-echoes t)
```

I have no idea why guile ignore that option